# Destring many, many variables, checking for non-numeric values

Tags: spss

Let's say I've imported data from excel that has many, many variables, say v1 through v4000. Each of these is intended to be numeric, and most cases have numeric-only values, but there are some cases that have non-numeric characters. For some of those non-numerics, I know the meaning (e.g., "NA" for missing), and potentially some unknown strings that should be investigated.

For each variable, I think I would like to do something like 1) create a numeric version of that variable that has the original values for all cases that had numeric values, 2) create a list of unique string values for cases with non-numerics so those can be investigated. With 4,000 variables, I would ideally use some type of loop to do this.

How can that be done? Is it even possible?

Comment: This question is too broad, please narrow it to one specific problem and post more questions for each separate focused problem. This will make it easier to help you and also make your questions more helpful for future users.

Comment: I'm honestly having trouble understanding how this very specific problem can be made more specific. Could you make a suggestion, @eli-k? I simply need to convert string to numeric for many variables, while somehow documenting the non-numeric values that are lost in that transition.

Comment: Some sample data and a sample desired output would help provide more context. However, if I understand your question correctly, I think there are other programming languages out there more suited for this kind of string parsing; SPSS is for data analysis (as the name suggests :)). My first thought would be python, and you can try with the original excel as input also

Comment: lol @horace_vr - my thoughts exactly! unfortunately that is not an option for me right now. Fortunately I did find a way to solve it that I'll post here in a moment

Comment: Still not clear if you've got cases where you've got a mixture of string and numbers you need to separate.  You need to narrow this question down from a general programming project to very specific tasks (eg. (1) separate text from numbers in cell (2), do this for many columns in a loop (3) create a unique list of string values from many columns) - for each of these tasks create a seperate question in which you explain the problem, show some sample data and what the desired output looks like, show what you've tried already.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts. I don't think I _need_ to do that as I've solved my problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the below macro, which creates a new variable with a "_str" suffix that holds the original values, and which can therefore be used to report frequencies of values that were turned into system missing values.

```
   DEFINE destringvars(names=!cmdend)
    !do !i !in (!names)
        RENAME VARIABLES (!i=!concat(!i,"_str")).
        STRING !i (A9).
        compute !i=!concat(!i,"_str").
        alter type !i(f8).
        TEMPORARY.
        SELECT if SYSMIS(!i).
        FREQUENCY !concat(!i,"_str").
    !DOEND        
    EXECUTE.
!enddefine
```

Comment: As the initial question is not clear, this answer might or might not be useful for future readers. Your code simply keeps the all-numeric values, and deletes everything else. My understanding was that you needed something very differently: extract numerical part and string part into separate variables. On Stack overflow, if you can't post some sample input, you'll rarely get useful answers, simply because people won't be able to understand proprly what you are after. You might get answers, but as general as your question.

Comment: Yes I see your point now. I edited the question in hopes of clarifying it.